Not to able to figure out why springboot give 401 error
I was trying to build personal project i got issue with Spring Security i am not able to reslove your help will appriciated
problem - > Problem is that even after configuratig security and flow of applicaition seems good it gives 401 error wheni try to save the club with proper credentails
I am not able to figure out wht is the problem
This is my security config class
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailServices;
    @Autowired
    private EntryPoint authEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public securityFilter authFilter() {
        return new securityFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailServices);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration auth) throws Exception {
        return auth.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf(csrf->csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->

                        auth
                                .requestMatchers(
                                        "/",
                                        "/api/v1/auth/signin",
                                        "/api/v1/auth/signup",
                                        "/api/v1/auth/**",
                                        "/v3/api-docs/**",
                                        "/v3/api-docs.yaml",
                                        "/swagger-ui/**",
                                        "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(authFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return httpSecurity.build();

    }
}

This is my controler
 @PostMapping("/new")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('MODERATOR')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveClub(@RequestBody ClubDto clubDto) {

        clubsService.saveClub(clubDto);
        Map<String, String> resp = new HashMap<>();
        resp.put("Message", "Club Registred Succesfully");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(resp);

    }

 @Override
    public void saveClub(ClubDto clubDto) {
        Clubs clubs = new Clubs();
        clubs.setTitle(clubDto.getClubName());
        clubs.setContent(clubDto.getContent());
        clubs.setCreatedOn(LocalDate.now());
        String userContext= (String)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        UserEntity user =userRepository.findByUsername(userContext).
                orElseThrow(()->new ResousrceNotFoundException("User not found"));
        clubs.getUserEntitySet().add(user);
        clubRepository.save(clubs);
    }

I tried @Secured Annotion its working in wierd way it is not authorizing the user; The user who doesnot have authoriazation to make request is also making request to authorize endpoint
I Tried logging th spring security
Failed to authorize ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.example.clubsapi.controller.ClubController.saveClub(com.example.clubsapi.dto.ClubDto); target is of class [com.example.clubsapi.controller.ClubController] with authorization manager org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.DeferringObservationAuthorizationManager@1137605f and decision ExpressionAuthorizationDecision [granted=false, expressionAttribute=hasRole('MODERATOR')]

I Got this log

What is the actual name of the role you are validating? Is it MODERATOR or ROLE_MODERATOR as currently it expects the last not the first.

'@PreAutorize' automailcally added 'ROLE_'  prefix to the MODERATOR; Thats why i wrote MODERATOR in' @PreAuthorize' and as an additional info Role is stored in DB as ROLE_MODERATOR

it is quite clear that you have followed a poor blogpost that doesnt know how security works than to actually read the spring security documentation. Handing out JWTs to browsers is dangerous and not recommended by many security sources and the spring team themselfes. authFilter() this should be completely deleted, and i would suggest that if you wish to use spring security you start out by reading the actual docs, and implement something like FormLogin to start with. JWTs should only be used in service to service calls between backend servers.

I know what it does, I wasn't sure you knew what it was doing. You wouldn't be the first with wrong expectations. If you get a 401 the roles aren't there or not what you think they are. So your filter is probably broken.

also. when we ask for logs, a single log line does not help us at all, we need context, we need to see what happens up until the error. Voted to close

Thanks EveryOne to respond to question; I solved it. it was very small mistake in it;
I was not returning authorities in getAuthorities(); It was set to Null and that was causing the
public class UserDetailsImp implements UserDetails {
    private int id;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public static UserDetailsImp build(UserEntity user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorityList = user.getRoles().stream()
                .map((role) -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new UserDetailsImp(
                user.getId(),
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                authorityList
        );
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}

